# My ListView won't save upon rotating the screen; using parcelable interface and onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, listview, screen-orientation

After a user submits a query and searches the api, a list is populated. But when I switch to landscape it disappears. I need to save it somehow. I've implemented a parcelable interface and added the methods for overriding and restoring onSaveInstanceState. What I have here is having no effect on the performance of my app and, unfortunately, I'm just not familiar enough with the new code to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Most of what I'm finding online assumes I know more than I do haha. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Book myClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the ListView.xml in the view hierarchy.
    ListView listItemView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Shows an empty text view when there's nothing to show
    mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    listItemView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

    // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of books as input
    mAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Book>());

    // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Populates the adapter with the list view xml file
    listItemView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("obj", myClass);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myClass=savedInstanceState.getParcelable("obj");
}
```

And my custom class:

```
public class Book implements Parcelable {

private int mData;

// Book title
private String mTitle;

// Book author
private String mAuthor;

/**
 * Create a new Book object
 * @param title is the title of the book
 * @param author is the author of the book
 */
public Book(String title, String author) {
    mTitle = title;
    mAuthor = author;
}

//Get the title of the book.
public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

//Get the author of the book.
public String getAuthor() {
    return mAuthor;
}

protected Book(Parcel in) {
    mTitle = in.readString();
    mAuthor = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mTitle);
    dest.writeString(mAuthor);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public Book createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Book(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Book[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Book[size];
    }
};
}
```

And my list adapter:

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

//constructor
public BookAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
    super(context, 0, books);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    // control-O automatically created
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the book at the current position on the list
    Book currentBook = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml with this ID
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    // Get the title from the current Book object and set it on the TextView
    titleTextView.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml with this ID
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.author_text);
    // Get the title from the current Book object and set it on the TextView
    authorTextView.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());

    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews)
    // so that it can be shown in the ListView
    return listItemView;
}
}
```

Comment: You are saving myClass instance and then you are restoring it. But why? You don't use it anywhere inside your code..

Comment: Your ListView is empty, right? Your ArrayList<Book> is empty

Comment: Could you provide a little more explanation? If I go based on your Title, am guessing that once you have rendered your `ListView`, if you change the `Orientation`, the `ListView` get re-rendered or such?? Is that whats happening?

Comment: It gets populated when a user submits a query to search the api

Comment: Yes, sorry. It disappears entirely. I'm assuming the activity is destroyed and I'm trying to stop that from happening or have it load again or something

Comment: Ok, got it. I think I know what you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```
mAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Book>());
```

you are passing an empty list of Book to the adapter of your ListView. So your ListView will be empty, because it has nothing to show.

Then you save `myClass` that is never instantiated as I can see, so you are saving a null object. Then you restore this null object.

What you must do is:

- create a list of Book and put them into an `ArrayList`
- pass previously created `ArrayList` to your `Adapter`
- to save data before rotation you must save your `ArrayList` into `onSaveInstanceState` method
- to restore data after rotation you must reget your `ArrayList` into `onRestoreInstanceState` method
- then recreate your Adapter with restored data and reassign it to your ListView

**Update**

Declare your ArrayList at Book myClass level `ArrayList<Book> bookList;`

Try split this line

```
mAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Book>());
```

into these two lines:

```
bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
mAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, bookList);
```

then in your `onSaveInstanceState`

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList("bookList", bookList);
```

and in your `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
bookList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("bookList");
```

After that you must recreate your `Adapter` and reassign it to your `ListView`

This should be the right way

Comment: Sorry, there is a list but the user has to search in order for it to populate. I left the code that deals with the internet out. It's a lot haha

Comment: Oh ok, but I think last 3 steps are useful however, or not?

Comment: Well, I'm just a bit confused. MyClass is my custom class <Book> which would be the ArrayList, right?

Comment: I put this line: outState.putParcelable("obj", myClass); in my override onSaveInstance method

Comment: No, myClass is the name of the instance of your Book class that you use into your Activity. An ArrayList is another class in which you can insert a list of some object (for object i mean an instance of a class). So your ArrayList should contain a list of your Book instances

Comment: with that line you are putting a single Book (permitted that you have already instantiated it somewhere) in the InstanceState, not your ArrayList

Comment: Ok. Any chance you can help me with the code for that?

Comment: I made a mistake: in onSaveInstanceState, now corrected. However if you have not clear what is an ArrayList I suggest you to read a Java tutorial. It will be well invested time to save a lot of time in the future ;)

Comment: @Emily if it worked please accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left of it ;)

Answer (score 1):

First create public `ArrayList<Book> list` object and you can set it to Adapter

```
ArrayList<Book> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Book>();
    list = getListData()// assign list values to list object
    .....
    mAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, list);

    .....
    .....
    listItemView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

when app getting rotating activity going `onSaveInstanceState` and destroyed activity.therefore you should that list value set to saveInstatantState object

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("obj", list);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

After that you can get that pass data value when occurring `onRestoreInstanceState` callback method on Activity.and you should set that list to adapter and refresh the Listview, If you can use Recyclerview instead Listview.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("obj");

        if (list != null) {
            mAdapter.addAll(list);
            ......

            listItemView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you will get a solution with this solution this is not full source correction. this is the solution you should to do technically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the `Orientation` is changed in your `Activity`, it re-renders the Layout. To stop that and retain the Layout View, add the following in your `android manifest file` :

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

This will override the default behaviour when orientation changes.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was told about this work-around but I'm not supposed to use it. I guess it suppresses the default behavior of android

Comment: Yes, but you can specify this for just the activity where the problem is occuring.

Comment: Ok. Well, if no one can give me an answer on the parcelable stuff and the new methods, I'll give you the green check.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.